# Contradicting definitions of numeric stability on wikipedia

Tags: numerical-methods, definition, numerical-calculus

### Summary of wikipedia article

Let

- $f$ be "a mathematical problem",
- $\tilde f$ a numerical scheme replicating $f$,
- $x$ the "input" to the problem, and
- $\tilde x$ the "perturbed input".

Then

- $\Vert f(\tilde x)-f(x) \Vert$, is called the **condition**, describing how the problem changes subject to a perturbed input,
- $\Vert \tilde f(\tilde x)-\tilde f(x) \Vert$, is called the **(numeric) stability**, describing how the scheme changes subject to a perturbed input,
- $\Vert \tilde f(x)-f(x) \Vert$, is called **consistency**, describing how well the scheme solves the problem when provided with the exact input
- $\Vert \tilde f(\tilde x)-f(x) \Vert$, is called **convergence**, describing how well the scheme solves the original problem.

Source: [This article on wikipedia in german language](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabilit%C3%A4t_(Numerik))

At first glance, this looked like a fantastic overview - sadly I dont understand it.

### My definition of Condition

The absolute condition number is the smallest number $\kappa$, such that
$$\Vert f(\tilde x)-f(x)\Vert \leq \kappa \Vert x-\tilde x\Vert$$

In other words, I would say the article did not explain "condition" in detail, but the concept is correct.

### My definition of Numeric stability

I was taught, that numerical schemes for ODEs/PDEs, that update a solution iteratively, i.e. algorithms described by an evolution operator, $E$, that computes a "new solution" $u^{n+1}$ as a function of $u^n$:
$$u^{n+1} = E u^{n}$$

are stable, if the operator norm of the evolution operator, is bounded by 1:
$$\Vert E \Vert \equiv \frac{\Vert E u^n\Vert}{\Vert u^n \Vert}\leq 1, \qquad \forall u^n$$

This is a measure for whether/how much "local" errors get amplified.

**Q1:** Is this definition of stability equivalent to the one from Wikipedia stated above? If so, how?

Choosing the letter $u$ for the unknown instead of $x$ was done intentionally, as I have a hard time making sense of the Wikipedia definition ("I dont know what they mean with $x$ - is it the unknown, or should it be a known variable, that we give as an 'input' to the problem?")

### My definition of Consistency

In my understanding, consistency of a Finite Difference or Volume method (not FEM), is the residual one gets from evaluating the exact solution with the scheme and then subtracting the original equation. This is a measure for how much error is introduced "locally"(=in every step). For a scheme $N$ and a differential operator $L$, consistency of $N$ is given if
$$N[u] - L[u] = \mathcal{E}(\Delta t, \Delta x)$$

where $u$ is the exact solution of $L[u]=0$ and the residual on the RHS, $\mathcal{E}$ (also called truncation error) converges to $0$ for $\Delta t, \Delta x\to 0$. From this we get the order of the scheme.

This definition seems to be consistent with Wikipedia, if we identify $N\equiv \tilde f$, $L\equiv f$, and $u\equiv x$. Note, that we have identified $x$ as the unknown, not as a known input to the problem, like suggested on Wikipedia.

### My definition of Convergence

For linear Finite Difference or Volume methods, one has this result from Lax and Richtmayr, stating that
$$\text{Stability and consistency}\iff \text{convergence}$$

If a method is convergent, it satisfies
$$\Vert u - u_h \Vert \xrightarrow{\Delta x, \Delta t \to 0} 0$$

**Q2:** Is this definition of convergence equivalent to the one from Wikipedia stated above? If so, how?

I have no idea if Wikipedia suggests, that $x=u$ here? If so, then why do they define convergence as $\Vert \tilde f(\tilde x) - f(x)\Vert$? Or does Wikipedia want me to believe that $f(x)\equiv u$, to be consistent with "my" definition of convergence, but then this would contradict the usage of $x$ from the Wikipedia definition of consistency.
It seems, from the Wikipedia definition, one can follow the Lax Richtmayr result. That would be great, if their notation would make sense.

---

### Summary:

- The definitions of **condition** and **consistency** make sense to me,
- the ones for **stability** and **convergence** dont.

Comment: To make matters worse, your bullet points give convergence the same definition as consistency (unless you've got a typo).

Comment: It was a typo. Thank you for the hint, i corrected it.

Comment: What you quote from Wikipedia is imo quite a schematic overview that leaves out details. Go with your concrete example that you understand and don't read WP as if it was the bible.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.